# Обработка потока данных

Tags: python

> Дана непустая последовательность целых чисел, оканчивающаяся нулем.
>   Ноль в последовательность не входит, служит признаком ее окончания.
>   Найти произведение последних цифр всех чисел последовательности,
>   больших числа 13

Мой код, который к сожалению не работает:

```
n = int(input())
count = 1
k = 0
while n != 0:
    n = int(input())
    if n > 13:
        k = k + 1
        count *= n % 10
if k == 0:
    print(0)
else:
    print(count)
```

Проходит 66,7% тестов. Даже не знаю что тут не так, задача простая то

Comment: ```14, 0``` - ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас первое n никак не обрабатывается.
Вы его запрашиваете, входите в цикл, потом ничего с этим первым n не делаете, и запрашиваете следующее.
Соответственно, у вас не будут проходить те тесты, в которых первое число последовательности > 13.

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так:

```
In [36]: from operator import mul

In [37]: from functools import reduce

In [38]: n = [13, 21, 22, 23, 9]

In [39]: reduce(mul, [x%10 for x in n if x>13])
Out[39]: 6
```

Comment: Последовательность, не простая. Она заканчивается нулем, что и сигнализирует о её конце

Comment: @Mikey_mouse, я привел решение без обработки строки введенной пользователем - это вы уже сделали в вопросе ;)